# Правка ответа, когда появились другие ответы

Tags: обсуждение

Такая ситуация:
Ответил ты на вопрос. Через некоторое время появляется еще несколько ответов и вместе с этим в своем ответе ты находишь неточности, которые следовало бы поправить. Но в ответах, которые появились позже твоего, эти неточности уже отмечены и исправлены. Как будет правильнее поступить в таком случае?
Исправить свой ответ, чтобы он не содержат неправильной информации или оставить как есть, потому что это исправление выглядит как "плагиат", хотя эти ответы никак не повлияли на твое исправление своего ответа?

Comment: если нашел неточность в своем ответе стоит его отредактировать

Comment: Сам нашёл — сам исправил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, даже: подсказали — сам исправил

Comment: @Grundy и так тоже.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Исправить, конечно, нужно, не дело, чтобы в ответе был баг только из-за сомнительного обвинения в плагиате.
А если ошибку нашли при помощи соседних ответов - вполне можно сделать приписку в постскриптуме вроде:
`Спасибо, @UserName, помог найти неточность`.

---

В конце-концов, плагиат - обвинение автору ответа, а ответ - достояние сообщества, он не должен от этого страдать.
В крайнем случае, можно отметить как общий.

Answer (score 3):

Если неточности обнаружены в течение 5 минут с момента первичной публикации, то правка даже не будет отражена в истории ревизий. Т.е. чисто теоретически можно первым дать совершенно левый ответ, и если за 5 минут кто-то даст ответ лучше - содрать его себе (всё в те же пять минут) и по дате публикации будет казаться, что ответ содрали с Вас! Делать так конечно же нехорошо :)

А хорошо делать так, как сказал Skyrocker в своём ответе.